# Drawing inside my own image

Tags: path, paint

I want to fill a shape with color or draw inside a shape that changes according to a user's choice.
for example a user choose a PNG of a heart shape and a color to fill it with and sees it on hes screen. now it doesnt have to be a heart it can be any png that the user want to upload.
I was able to do that with the following code inside onDraw methode:

```
canvas.drawPath(heartPath, mPaintFilling);
canvas.clipPath(heartPath, Op.REPLACE);
```

and then fill the path, but i cant find a way to make a path out of a drawable Scope.

Comment: By path you mean the border of the heart (or any shape)?

Comment: That's exactly what i ment, but instead of creating a path manually i want to create a path of a specific PNG's scope.

Comment: Well I'm not sure as to how you would accomplish this, as there is no trivial solution for it. You need to look for / create software that processes a png and reports a border. I'd imagine that this software finds the border by finding contrast between pixels, i.e. finding RGB.White untill it sees a border (RGB.Black), and reporting the coordinates of the pixel.

Comment: Can you please suggest a program that does it?

Comment: No, I have no idea, and I couldn't expect my googling to be more effective than your own.